# Cannot install appx through graphic installer

Tags: windows-10-universal, appx, desktop-bridge, desktop-app-converter

I'm facing a problem right now and I don't really know how to get more informations about it.

I've converted a desktop application through Microsoft's Desktop App Converter, made some manual modifications about the visual assets, and rebundled it through "makeappx.exe". Then I signed it.

Everything went fine. Except that when I double click the appx to check it, I have the following window:

[Appx Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50bqU.png)

Which roughly translates as "Couldn't open the appx or appxbundle file" and "Reason: Failure caused by an unknown reason".

This does not helps me a lot :/

However, if I try to install the package through a simple "Add-appxpackage MyPackage.appx", it works perfectly fine.

Could anyone help me find some leads on what's happening here? I've already checked the event viewer as explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh973484(v=vs.85).aspx) but I couldn't find anything unusual.

Thanks,

Skefrep

Comment: I have the same problem, I think is something broken when we installed one of Windows updates. Some colleagues in my office managed to fix it by installing the Desktop App Converter from the store, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: @BogdanMitrache I've updated it from the store too. I'll try to recreate my appx from another computer, maybe this would work.

Comment: I doubt, I've created tens of AppX packages, and also got others built by others and still doesn't work. The problem is within the OS, not the package (otherwise it wouldn't work with PS command), maybe something with event (double-click) handlers registered in the system, I don't know for sure. :(

Comment: Yes, it didn't work... I hope this will be fixed soon... Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: I have the same problem, and happened after modifying it to comply with Windows Store parameters. I regenerated also the certificate to change the CN to match the Store parameters. Add-AppxPackage works but no the graphical tool

Comment: For the author: please these tags: project-centennial and desktop-bridge microsoft staff monitor these tags. Your edit queue is full so I cannot add them myself.

Comment: @CarlosRafaelRamirez Thanks for the tags. I've directly sent an e-mail to one of the contacts I have in the Microsoft team who worked on centennial but didn't get an answer so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the Microsoft team has taken notice of this problem and investigated this appropriately.

[-Here is their solution-](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appconsult/2017/05/31/failed-due-to-unknown-reasons-error-when-you-try-to-sideload-a-desktop-bridge-app/)

Comment: Perfect ! There was an error in my makepri command, if I follow their recommandations it works. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is better if you add more info to the answer (for example the commands used) instead of only a link.

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be because when you convert an app with DesktopBridge the resources are signed with the manifest info and store that info in the `.pri` files you found in PackageFiles folder. Later, when you change something like the Publisher or the Name this signature doesn't match. To fix this you only need to recreate the .pri files.

1. `rm *.pri`. Remove the old `.pri` files.
2. `cd C:\foo\PackageFiles\`. Change current directory to the PackageFiles folder. This step **is important** for the next step.
3. `makepri createconfig /cf priconfig.xml /dq en-US`. Create a configuration file for the resources.
4. `makepri new /pr "C:\foo\PackageFiles" /cf "C:\foo\PackageFiles\priconfig.xml"`. Generate the new `*.pri` files.
5. Then you can make the package as usual: `MakeAppx`, etc.

You can find more information about this problem in ["Failed due to unknown reasons" error when you try to sideload a Desktop Bridge app - App Consult Team](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appconsult/2017/05/31/failed-due-to-unknown-reasons-error-when-you-try-to-sideload-a-desktop-bridge-app/).

Comment: Hi @PhoneixS With the latest update in visual studio, I can create a package appxbundle with just few clicks and I don't have package files separately, but 
I am also facing this issue, tried searching a lot but no answers so far!

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what can be as I don't have the latest version.